# No output with JavaScript forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm obviously not understanding how forEach works in JavaScript, because when I run the following code, **I don't get any output at all**. What am I misunderstanding or doing wrong? Thanks!

```
var id = [];
id['battery'] = [];
id['battery']['garage'] = 27;
id['battery']['attic'] = 88;
id['battery']['basement'] = 74;
id['battery']['office'] = 62;
id['battery']['hallway'] = 84;

id['battery'].forEach(function(value, room) {
    console.log("value = " + value + " | room = " + room);
});
```

Comment: `forEach` only iterates over the keys of the array which are positive integers.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays; `.forEach()` only iterates through integer-indexed properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: Thank you. I know it was a dumb question, but I've been switching between PHP and JavaScript and was temporarily confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `forEach` with objects. But you can do this:

```
var id = {
  battery: {
    garage: 27,
    attic: 88,
    basement: 74,
    office: 62,
    hallway: 84
  }
};

for(var room in id.battery) {
    console.log("value = " + id.battery[room] + " | room = " + room);
};
```

Comment: In such case there should also be an if statement `if ( id.battery.hasOwnProperty(room) )`